# treat something to something else

Tags: comprehension

Source: [The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript by Nicholas C. Zakas (2014)](https://www.nostarch.com/oojs)

Example:

> My relationship with Nicholas comes from years of studying his books,
>   reading his blog posts, watching him speak, and monitoring his Twitter
>   updates as a JavaScript pupil. We first met in person when I asked him
>   to speak at a jQuery conference several years ago. He **treated the jQuery
>   community to a high-quality talk**, and since then, we have spoken publicly
>   and privately over the Internet.

As far as I know, this idiomatic expression is usually used with food. For example: *You've done a very good job for me. Now, as a reward, let me treat you to a cup of gourmet coffee you have never had in your entire life*. And it makes sense because the verb *treat* when used with food items typically means *to give someone something tasty*. But I don't think I understand how it's being used in the paragraph. And what does it actually say, semantically speaking? He took all the members of the community and presented them at a very important talk?

Comment: "Treat" in this sense speaks to getting more than was expected, both in the content of the talk, and the manner in which Nicholas delivered it.

Comment: I don't think that in *let me treat you to a cup of gourmet coffee*, the verb *treat* is used because it's tasty. It's more like it's because it's special, so it's a treat. This high-quality talk could be considered a treat as well, imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To treat* doesn't have to be used with food, it can be used with anything that is potentially enticing or enjoyable to the recipient and given freely by the subject.

> Bob is going to treat Sally to a movie.

Bob is going to pay for Sally's movie, and not expect to be paid back.

The above isn't really an idiom, it's just a common meaning of *treat* as a verb.